# NNID and Club Nintendo

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u, club-nintendo

If say, I have linked my club Nintendo account to my NNID, but at one point I want to have a new NNID for whatever reason, if I re-link the Club Nintendo account to my new NNID, then unlink it from my old NNID, will I still have the stars/coins for the codes I added. I assume the answer is yes, though I want to make sure.

Comment: Please, try to ask only ONE question at time

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. The NNID and CN (Club Nintendo) accounts can exist separately, and relinking to other NNID is possible. Though only one NNID can be linked, so if you want both Wii U and 3DS to produce stars from purchases they must use same NNID.

Comment: Personally I'd avoid swapping NNIDs against a Club Nintendo account after they were linked. The whole digital content system is fragile enough that it seems like you're just inviting trouble.

Comment: @BryanC. I personally switched NNID to CN link, worked fine for me.